# How to return activeworkbook path on Excel for Mac?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the file path of the active workbook using "application.activeworkbook.path".

This code works on PC, however, when I run it on Mac, the path returned is "/Users/(username)/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/", which seems to be a temp file directory of some kind and not the actual local file location.  How can I get the real file path?